# How can i change the size of the "worm" in my game?

Tags: python, pygame

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would i change the width of the snake in my “snake game”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867925/how-would-i-change-the-width-of-the-snake-in-my-snake-game)

Im using python and pygame:
How can i change the width of the "worm" in my game? So far the snake is only 1 pixel wide how can i change the width to be 3 or 4 pixels wide?

```
class Worm:
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = surface.get_width()/2
        self.y = surface.get_height()/2
        self.length = 5
        self.grow_to = 50
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = -1
        self.body = []
        self.crashed = False
        self.color = (255, 255, 0)




    def move(self):
        """Move the worm"""
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy

        if (self.x, self.y) in self.body:
            self.crashed = True

        self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y))

        if (self.grow_to > self.length):
            self.length += 1

        if len(self.body) > self.length:
            self.body.pop()

    def draw(self):
       for x, y in self.body:
           self.surface.set_at((x, y), self.color)

    def position (self):
        return self.x, self.y

    def eat(self):
        self.grow_to += 25
```

NEW CODE____________________________ But this causes the snake to grow continuesly

```
class Worm:
    def __init__(self, surface):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = surface.get_width()/2
        self.y = surface.get_height()/2
        self.length = 5
        self.grow_to = 50
        self.vx = 0
        self.vy = -1
        self.body = []
        self.crashed = False
        self.color = (255, 255, 0)

    def move(self):
        """Move the worm"""
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy

        if (self.x, self.y) in self.body:
            self.crashed = True

        self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y))
        self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y+1))
        self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y-1))
        self.body.insert(0, (self.x+1, self.y))
        self.body.insert(0, (self.x-1, self.y))

        if (self.grow_to > self.length):
            self.length += 1

        if len(self.body) > self.length:
            self.body.pop()

    def draw(self):
       for x, y in self.body:
           self.surface.set_at((x, y), self.color)
       for x, y in self.body:
           self.surface.set_at((x, y), self.color)

    def position (self):
        return self.x, self.y
        return self.x, self.y+1
        return self.x, self.y-1
        return self.x+1, self.y
        return self.x-1, self.y

    def eat(self):
        self.grow_to += 25
```

Comment: How are you drawing the snake? Pygame, I assume, but are you using `pygame.draw.rect(self.image,color,[xpos,ypos,width,height])`...?

Comment: No im using     `self.surface.set_at((x, y), self.color)`

Comment: `Surface.set_at` is designed for placing a coloured pixel, so depending on which way the snake is facing, run `surface.set_at` two or three times, each time adding 1 pixel to the x value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grow it thicker with

```
 self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y))
 self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y+1))
 self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y-1))
 self.body.insert(0, (self.x+1, self.y))
 self.body.insert(0, (self.x-1, self.y))
   ...   # corner cases if they are important
```

draw() will automatically take in the new pixels in body. Nice game, I hacked it on Nokia PyS60 some time ago.

Comment: Now when i did your suggestion the snake moves faster than it deletes its "tail" so its continueslly growing.

Comment: You are right, it should actually add only in y direction when moving in x, and vice versa.

Comment: Like in the pseudo-code below, the program should check the direction and add pixels only in the other direction to avoid growing the snake length. I don't know how to format the comments so you need to fix the whitespace below :-(

if self.vy != 0: self.body.insert(0, (self.x+1, self.y)) self.body.insert(0, (self.x-1, self.y)) if self.vx != 0: self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y+1)) self.body.insert(0, (self.x, self.y-1))

Answer (score 0):

`Surface.set_at` is for placing colored pixels, however by manipulating the `x` value, or `y` value, you should be able to run that code through a loop and get it to print out multiple times.

**Edit:** Sorry, the code should add to the Y value to make the snake 'thicker'...

This is **pseudo-code**:

```
#Snake
for snakeLength in range(3):
    if Snake is facing right:
        self.surface.set_at((x, y+snakeLength), self.color)
```

That's my idea of doing that, but it's untested sorry.  I use sprites usually.

**Edit:** [Pygame Docs](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.set_at), "*Getting and setting pixels one at a time is generally too slow to be used in a game or realtime situation.* "